# Relinking existing user profiles after User Profile Service recreated

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I'm having the following issue in SharePoint 2013.

I'm using Active Directory import to bring in user information from AD to SharePoint. Since the AD structure was changed (in order to clean up the AD), some of the sync got out of sync and user's titles and names were not being changed in SharePoint even though they were changed in AD. This out-of-sync was also affecting user permissions by SharePoint removing a user's access to certain sites

In order to fix this issue (of users losing permissions on sites if they opened a Office Web Apps document for example), I deleted the User Profile Service by also checking the *"Delete data associated with this service."* After I recreated the User Profile Service and did a new AD import, all the user data (title, names, emails) were imported from AD, but the "About Me" link on the top right corner was gone.

The previous profiles of users have a lot of data (blogs, images) that the user posted on their profile page like images, likes, infos, blog posts etc.

My question is is it possible to link the existing profiles to the SharePoint now since the "About Me" link is gone? I don't want to lose any previous user profile data.

If I go to for instance *http://mysite/personal/person_a/blog*, the site exists because my sites is created in a separate site collection.

Does User Profile Service (delete with data), delete the My Sites configuration (since the "About Me") is gone? Do I have to recreate the My Sites using the template? If I recreate the My Sites, does it override the existing user profile data at like "/personal/person_a" gets deleted/overridden and recreated at the same location at "/personal/person_a" or does it know that an existing profile exists and links with the existing profile?

Right now, "My settings" link next to the username displays the profile image that I uploaded on my earlier My Profile page.

What are the steps necessary to link "About Me" to the existing/previous user profile sites? Is it even possible?